# Going back from a navigation drawer activity crashes the app

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin

I'm learning how to make an app with google sign-in capabilities from the tutorial [here](https://grokonez.com/android/kotlin-firebase-authentication-google-sign-in-android) and ran into some problems when trying to go back from a `navigation-drawer` activity. How it works is that first the `GoogleSigninAcitivity` will be launched for the user to sign in. Once the sign in is approved, I would then start a navigation-drawer activity `Main2Activity`. Once a specific item in the drawer is clicked, I would end `Main2Activity` and go back to `GoogleSigninAcitivity` and proceed to sign-out. However in this case, the app crashes as soon as I click the drawer item which in this case is named `nav_share`.

Here is the code for `GoogleSigninActivity`:

```
package nus.is3261.kotlinapp

import android.app.Activity
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_google_signin.*
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
import android.content.Intent
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider

class GoogleSigninActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private val TAG = "JSAGoogleSignIn"
    private val REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN = 1234
    private val REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_OUT = 123
    private val WEB_CLIENT_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"

    private var mAuth: FirebaseAuth? = null

    private var mGoogleApiClient: GoogleApiClient? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_signin)

        btn_sign_in.setOnClickListener(this)
        btn_sign_out.setOnClickListener(this)
        btn_disconnect.setOnClickListener(this)

        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(WEB_CLIENT_ID)
                .requestEmail()
                .build()

        mGoogleApiClient = GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build()

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        val currentUser = mAuth!!.currentUser
        updateUI(currentUser)
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        val i = v!!.id

        when (i) {
            R.id.btn_sign_in -> signIn()
            R.id.btn_sign_out -> signOut()
            R.id.btn_disconnect -> revokeAccess()
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent();
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN) {
            val result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data)
            if (result.isSuccess) {
                // successful -> authenticate with Firebase
                val account = result.signInAccount
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account!!)
            } else {
                // failed -> update UI
                updateUI(null)
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "SignIn: failed!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        } else if ((requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_OUT)&&(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)){
            mGoogleApiClient?.connect()
            signOut()
        }
    }

    private fun firebaseAuthWithGoogle(acct: GoogleSignInAccount) {
        Log.e(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle():" + acct.id!!)

        val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.idToken, null)
        mAuth!!.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        // Sign in success
                        Log.e(TAG, "signInWithCredential: Success!")
                        val user = mAuth!!.currentUser
                        updateUI(user)
                    } else {
                        // Sign in fails
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential: Failed!", task.exception)
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Authentication failed!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        updateUI(null)
                    }
                }
    }

    override fun onConnectionFailed(connectionResult: ConnectionResult) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onConnectionFailed():" + connectionResult);
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Google Play Services error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private fun signIn() {
        val intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient)
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN)
    }

    private fun signOut() {
        // sign out Firebase
        mAuth!!.signOut()

        // sign out Google
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback { updateUI(null) }
    }

    private fun revokeAccess() {
        // sign out Firebase
        mAuth!!.signOut()

        // revoke access Google
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback { updateUI(null) }
    }

    private fun updateUI(user: FirebaseUser?) {
        if (user != null) {
            val myIntent = Intent(this, Main2Activity::class.java)
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_OUT)
//            tvStatus.text = "Google User email: " + user.email!!
//            tvDetail.text = "Firebase User ID: " + user.uid

//            btn_sign_in.visibility = View.GONE
//            layout_sign_out_and_disconnect.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            tvStatus.text = "Signed Out"
            tvDetail.text = null

            btn_sign_in.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            layout_sign_out_and_disconnect.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }

}
```

Here is where I return from `Main2Activity`:

```
override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.nav_basics -> {
            basicFragment()
        }
        R.id.nav_loops -> {
            loopFragment()
        }
        R.id.nav_functions -> {
            functionFragment()
        }
        R.id.nav_chart -> {

        }
        R.id.nav_share -> {
            signOut()
            return true
        }
    }

    drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    return true
}

fun signOut(){
    drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    val myIntent = Intent()
    myIntent.putExtra("SignOut", "SignOut")
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, myIntent)
    finish()
}
```

I feel like I am doing something wrong, but I cant seem to find out where the error is.
Here is the logcat error shown as soon as I click `nav_share`: The words which are cut off are saying `GoogleApiCliet is not connected yet`

[image]

Comment: Please show the error logcat.

Comment: @SonTruong ok I added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are moving to other activity and then calling below code

```
drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
```

But you need to first execute this code and then proceed for any redirection.
Reason behind this is that you would get drawer_layout as null when you have already redirected to another activity.
Hope it helps

Comment: I edited it and tried calling it first as shown above, but the app still crashes

Comment: You didn't connect your googleApiClient, you need to call     mGoogleApiClient.connect(); just after you have built the object of GoogleApiClient. Once you call it, onConnected (overridden) method will be invoked.

Comment: Hmmm, good point, the app still crashed after I did that though

Comment: The problem may be with lifecycle of your activity, so you can try putting the mGoogleApiClient.connect() in onResume() of activity. If you find it null in onResume then you need to recreate it.

Answer (score 2):

Check in signout method `mGoogleApiClient` is properly initialized and connected. otherwise you can call `mGoogleApiClient.connect()` before calling `signout`

```
private fun signOut() {
        // sign out Firebase
        mAuth!!.signOut()

        // sign out Google
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback { updateUI(null) }
    }
```

Comment: it should be as connected and working properly as everything was working fine when I was implementing it on one activity `GoogleSigninActivity`, i could log out and log in fine. Is there a chance that it will disconnect if i go to another activity ? I tried adding `mGoogleApiCLident.connect` right before I sign out but it still crashed.

Comment: have you debugged it is connected or not?

Comment: nah, it still was not connected, I then decided to do it all within a single activity instead of between activities. thanks for the help though !